Changing Custom Footer with Polylang on JupiterX theme
Actually I will write the solution. I couldn't find the solution anywhere for JupiterX so probably someone also looking for this solution.
I prepared this solution for Turkish and English. So before using it be careful about language code and template ids.

Prepare your custom template for footer in languages you want and note template ids. Also create one empty footer template and make it default footer. If you will not do it JupiterX will show 2 footers at the same time in every language.

Create 2 php files in the theme folder. I created as footer-tr.php and footer-en.php

Insert following code in the php files you created with template id for specific language.


<?php
// Call Elementor Turkish footer template
echo do_shortcode( '[elementor-template id="Turkish_Template_ID"]' );
?>


Open functions.php file from Theme file editor and insert following code.

add_action( 'get_footer', 'load_dynamic_footer' );

function load_dynamic_footer() {
    if ( function_exists( 'pll_current_language' ) ) {
        $current_language = pll_current_language();

        if ( $current_language == 'tr' ) {
            get_template_part( 'footer', 'tr' );
        } elseif ( $current_language == 'en' ) {
            get_template_part( 'footer', 'en' );
        }
    }
}

